# How two achieve a two dimesional vector in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I want to make a two-dimensional vector that is holding two numeric values.
As usual vectors (even of different numerical type) should e.g. be addable.
In C++ you can just do something like:

```
template<typename T>
class vector2d{

    T x{0};
    T y{0};

public:
    template<typename U> vector2d& operator+=(const vector2d<U>& vec){
        x += vec.x;
        y += vec.y;
        return *this;
    }
    ...

template<typename U>
friend class vector2d;
};
```

But when I try to achieve this in Java I am coming across some problems.
Here is what I tried to do:

```
class vector2d<T extends Number>{

    private T x;
    private T y;

    public <U extends Number> vector2d add(vector2d<U> vec){
        x += vec.x;
        y += vec.y;
        return this;
    }
    ... 
}
```

But this does not work. It would if i would use Integer or Float or whatever directly (because of Autoboxing). But this seems not to be the case when you just use the Number class directly. As I think there is no other interface that would satisfy the requirements, I am kind of stuck here.
So my question is if there are ways to make this work in Java.

Comment: What's wrong with your example? What do you expect to happen and what is happening instead?

Comment: "But this does not work" - is no sufficient description of the Problem you are facing. Do you have compiler errors?

Comment: `x += vec.x;` won't work since `x` is private

Comment: This is not possible because the compiler will not accept this as there is no "+=" operation for numbers. It only works because of autoboxing for Integer, Float and so on (as I said).

Comment: @ArcticLord Yeah that could be. I'll make it public because that is not the problem here.

Comment: No, @ArcticLord is wrong, this has nothing to do with `x` being `private`. You cannot use `+=` on `Number` objects in Java. Note that Java generics do not work in the same way as C++ templates.

Comment: Java does not support this because the actions are not well defined for Java type system. Suppose we have `vector2d<Integer> intVec` and `vector2d<Double> doubleVec` with `doubleVec.x = Double.MAX_VALUE`. What would you expect the value of `intVec.add(doubleVec).x` to be? What if `doubleVec.x = Double.NaN`?

Comment: @Jesper Unfortunately you are right. But honestly I'm surprised every time I am using them how restricted they really are compared to C++ templates, as you can see at this really basic example.

Answer (score 2):

One of possibilities to achieve this, is use `BigDecimal` class:

```
class vector2d{

    private BigDecimal x;
    private BigDecimal y;

    public void add(vector2d vec){
        x = x.add(vec.x);
        y = y.add(vec.y);
    }
    ...
}
```

But it can reduce performance of your code, as its operations aren't very fast.
You can also keep `Number` class and use `doubleValue` always:

```
class vector2d{

    private Number x;
    private Number y;

    ...

    public void add(vector2d vec){
        x = x.doubleValue() + vec.x.doubleValue();
        y = y.doubleValue() + vec.y.doubleValue();
    }
```

}

this will allow use any types of numbers:

```
    vector2d v1 = new vector2d(1, 2.3);
    vector2d v2 = new vector2d(1.3, 2);
    v1.add(v2);
```

**UPD**: As @Jesper has mentioned, instead of `Number` just `double` type can be used, which will eliminate need of `.doubleValue()` invocation. So you have various way to do it.

Comment: Why not make `x` and `y` of type `double`? Then you wouldn't have unnecessary boxing and unboxing.

Comment: @Jesper, exactly, but just in case if `Number` type is needed for some reasons :)

Comment: Yeah but this is not really satisfying as e.g. if you want to add two "Integral Vectors" you may do this without losing precision. And just imagine using user-defined Number types.